# What is the difference between a software quality analyst, and a software tester

Tags: manual-testing, terminology, standards

I'm learning about software quality assurance on my own (self-education). I am using a lot of youtube videos and I'm also googling some of questions. I have just realized that there are differences between SQA and Software tester. So can someone explain to me, why/how are they different from each other?

Answer (score 5):

**Software quality analyst** is responsible for applying the principles and practices of software quality assurance throughout the software development life cycle.

Some of the tasks of software quality analysts are:[citation needed]

- Participate in QMS management review meetings.
- Approves the QMS documents of which QA manager is the main author.
- Undertake internal quality audits.
- Plan and conduct quality audits of subcontractors.
- Maintain and update training and audit databases to provide reports /   indicators for discussion during QMS management review meetings
- Identify problems or deficiencies in products and QMS.
- Resolve problems QMS implementation issues.
- Perform Internal Quality Audit.
- Participate in External Quality Audit.
- Track all the software related metrics in terms of schedule,effort,defects etc.
- Review the model followed by project.

**Software Tester :**

A technician who conducts prescribed tests on software programs and applications prior to their implementation to ensure quality, design integrity and proper functionality. They apply rigorous testing methods including extensive end-user simulations to uncover program "bugs" which are then eliminated by the software programmers.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it is important to understand the difference between testing and QA.

There is one post you need to read on the topic by Michael Bolton, [Testers get out of the QA business](http://www.developsense.com/blog/2010/05/testers-get-out-of-the-quality-assurance-business/).

The short version is that testers, who don't change code, are *assisting* with quality, not *assuring* it.

Answer (score 2):

To put it simple:

QA is a **process**-oriented activity - evaluation, review and improvement of processes across the software development life cycle. Better processes=>better product (quality).

QC (Quality Control) is **product**-oriented and involves dynamic testing and static techniques such as reviews, inspections etc. Products are e.g. specifications, design documents, code itself, database models etc.

Testing is not a QA activity. However, it provides inputs (e.g. root cause analysis of an issue might discover a problem in the development processes) and therefore they are related.

Technically speaking, quality analyst would be someone doing QA activities..or it can be someone dealing with non-functional requirements (qualities) of the system.
In the end, it always depend on the company and its culture. I have seen so many companies calling manual testers "QA Analysts".